# Different styles within the same Word Table cell using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a XLS to Word document automation project where 2 strings `String1` and `String2` needs to be assigned to a Word table cell. The challenge is to have String1 in red italics font style and String2 in black normal font style. How do i achieve this ?

My present code makes all text to red itallic, which is the default table font style.

```
With wdoc.Tables(pos)
     .Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = String1
     wapp.Selection.Font.Italic = False
     wapp.Selection.Font.Color = wdColorAutomatic
     .Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = .Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text & String2
End with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea I could think of is to use references to the range based on the position of your text within the whole document. The below code find values of two properties: `.Start` and `.End` of your cell text, check length of both `String1` and `String2` texts. All are used as `Document.Range(Start,End)` parameters. So, the code will look as follows (add it after your code:

```
With wdoc.Tables(pos).Rows(1).Cells(1).Range
        With wdoc.Range(.Start, .Start + Len(String1)).Font
            .Italic = True
            .Color = vbRed
        End With
        With wdoc.Range(.End - Len(String2), .End).Font
            'do nothing assuming text is black/standard
            'or change to black if necessary
        End With
End With
```